# How could I check the loaded drivers and their versions?

Tags: centos, linux-device-driver, hardware, centos6.5

The operating system is `CentOS 6.5`, we could use the following commands for hardware information:

```
   cat /proc/cpuinfo
   cat /proc/meminfo
   lspci
   lsusb
```

And, how could I get the drivers of these hardware and their versions? Does it need root access? Thank you!

**UPDATED**
[image]

Comment: Have you tried the modinfo utility?  'modinfo foomod'

Comment: @PeterL., thank you for replying! I have used the `lspci -V`, it would output some information, but in fact I want to know what's the version of the loaded drivers without root privilege.

Comment: On the distro I'm using (SLES 11) modinfo is under /sbin but can be executed by anyone.  Try using lsmod to find the module that you are interested in and then try modinfo with it.

Comment: OK, thanks. I've tried `lsmod` and `modinfo`, that's very helpful! But it seems that it couldn't output the graphics card located in `PCI Express 16x`. I've setup a graphics card in PCI slots. But the `lsmod` couldn't retrieve it. I've updated the post with a figure, please kindly check it. Thanks!

Comment: Try using `lspci -k` or `lspci -vv` to find the driver(s).  I can't see the linked image from my current location.  The graphics drivers interface with `drm`.  `lspci` will show the driver dependencies.

Comment: @PeterL., thanks. These commands are very helpful! I use the `lsmod`, there isn't the `drm` in the results. And I indeed setup the graphics card and could use it to do computing. Maybe it is because that I use the `VNC Viewer` to remotely control the machine, so it doesn't need the `VGA` driver, then the `lsmod` couldn't find it.

Comment: Perhaps this machine is not at a runlevel that would load the graphics driver.  However, I do see `nvidia` and `vesafb` (framebuffer) drivers loaded.  (I can see the image you posted from my location now).  Those might be interesting drivers in your investigation.  NVIDIA also makes (or used to) motherboard components other than graphics and the code that drives them, so maybe that `nvidia` driver is not for graphics, but I would guess that it is.

Comment: @PeterL., Yeah! You are absolutely right! I use the `NVIDIA` card, and the machine (`slave1` in the figure) is used to do some computing, and I connect it by `ssh` using `VNC Viewer`. You are an expert, who knows the `vesafb` is from `NVIDIA` driver. In fact, I connect another machine, which I haven't the root access, but I could use the `lspci` to know there is `NVIDIA` card that has been on it. But I didn't know which version of the driver. And thank you very much for there useful commands in your kindly comments! And now the manager has setup the driver in that machine.